# Are there any example projects that use Kohana with user registration and login authentification?

Tags: php, kohana

I want to make an web application (platform) that does pretty straightforward stuff: Users can register, get an account, and therefore login on to the platform. I've installed Kohana. It would be cool to have a lightweight demo-project that makes use of these things in order to see how it's done.

Are there any good ones available?

Comment: Check out here: https://github.com/synapsestudios/kohana-projecttemplate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gallery3 Beta](http://gallery.menalto.com/gallery_3.0_beta_1_released) and [Argentum Invoice](http://www.argentuminvoice.com/) are both built on Kohana and have authentication.

Answer (score 3):

A ready to download example based on kohana 3.2.
http://www.workinprogress.ca/kohana32/

Answer (score 1):

The auth module that comes bundled with Kohana allows you to manager simple user/role logins.
It does not provide forms for registration/user management however.

Comment: That would be just fine. I'm looking for examples on how to set this authentification up...

Comment: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/addons/auth
there are also some other auth modules in the the kohana modules list on their website

Comment: It's funny, I've tried following the kohana documentation, but the auth documentation for 2.x, their example code showing how to use it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am just setting up a project using Kohana 3.2 and Auth Module and found these useful guides:

Setting up the basic Auth in KO3 (part 1): http://blog.mixu.net/2010/09/06/step-by-step-guide-to-kohana-3-auth/

An overview of the functionality provided by the Auth module (part 2): http://blog.mixu.net/2010/09/07/kohana-3-auth-the-auth-module-functionality/

Tips on implementing Auth in a custom application (part 3): http://blog.mixu.net/2010/09/14/kohana-3-auth-sample-implementation-and-documentation/

Getting started with Useradmin, my Kohana 3 auth admin module (part 4): http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/13/getting-started-with-useradmin-my-kohana-3-auth-admin-module/