# Is there any skeleton project made with Kohana that makes use of authentification and database?

Tags: php, kohana

To get started with Kohana quickly, I wonder if someone has ever made an sleek skeleton project that makes use of all basic things every web developer needs:

- basic user authentification with login
- retrieving some stuff from an MySQL database and displaying it

By hand I would do this pretty fast. But with Kohana it feels like I have to climb up the Mont Everest to achieve it. They don't provide any complete examples, just code fragments for all kind of stuff. It would be cool to have some "basic shape" from where to start making an dynamic platform. I mean, nowadays alsmost every website needs to have some kind of authentification, login and stuff like this.

If anyone knows a simple basic working skeleton project example that's not blown up with tons of freak stuff like ajax & co, a link would be cool.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966862/are-there-any-example-projects-that-use-kohana-with-user-registration-and-login-a

Answer (score 1):

This project/tutorial looks like it'd be worth checking out: http://remorse.nl/weblog/kohana_auth_module_a_better_one/. It was written by someone who wasn't very happy with the default auth module in Kohana.